# What is the equivalent of Spring RequestContextHolder in Jersey/Dropwizard

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, aspectj, dropwizard

I am new to Dropwizard and we need to fetch the `HttpServletRequest` object in our AspectJ project(native not AOP). AspectJ project is used as a framework(jar) in different projects of different framework

Below code is get `HttpServletRequest` for spring boot project.

```java
Class<?> requestHolder = Class.forName("org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder");
Method method = requestHolder.getMethod("currentRequestAttributes");
Object currentAttributes = method.invoke(requestHolder);
Class<?> servletAttributes = Class.forName("org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes");
currentAttributes = servletAttributes.cast(currentAttributes);
method = currentAttributes.getClass().getMethod("getRequest");
Object httpRequest = method.invoke(currentAttributes);
if (httpRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
    return (HttpServletRequest) httpRequest;
}
```

How to do for Jersey/Dopwizard?

Comment: There is no equivalent but I imagine you could easily make something similar. Just look at the source code.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am unable to understand in Jersey, from where httpservelet object can be fetche

Comment: The earliest point in the request would be in a servlet filter.

Comment: You might even try to tap into the injection system. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about AspectJ to offer any guidance. HttpServletRequest can certainly be injected anywhere in a Jersey application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could inject the HttpServletRequest Object in your code as below

```
@Inject
private Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider;
```

You could provide a method in you WebService class to access this request object.
In your aspects you could use reflection to invoke this method and access the HttpServletRequest

AspectJ Part:
Create an annotation that can be applied over the rest service method that triggers the aspect advice before/around/after method execution based on how you want to write it. Within the advice we invoke the getHTTPServlet method call by fetching the target object from the joinPoint

Comment: Create an annotation that can be applied over the rest service method that triggers the aspect advice before/around/after method execution based on how you want to write it. Within the advice we invoke the getHTTPServlet method call by fetching the target object from the joinPoint.